# Issues with complex processing use-case in ksqlDB

Tags: ksqldb

I've been trying to get a ksql query up and running which is meant to process the following records:

```json
{
  "id": "2bc9461a-96e3-479f-95e2-ee7238954010",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "referenceId": "3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c91d4a48bd26",
      "type": "ARTICLE",
      "quantity": 1,
      "unitPrice": "5",
      "basePrice": "5",
      "lineTotal": "5",
      "taxRate": "7",
      "priceModifiers": []
    },
    {
      "referenceId": "aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-da18a7de082a",
      "type": "ARTICLE",
      "quantity": 1,
      "unitPrice": "3",
      "basePrice": "3",
      "lineTotal": "3",
      "taxRate": "7",
      "priceModifiers": []
    }
  ],
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": "3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c91d4a48bd26",
      "name": "Test1",
      "plu": "9001",
      "articleGroupId": "c2ac3dfc-c176-4655-b725-ae6eb01c60a7"
    },
    {
      "id": "aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-da18a7de082a",
      "name": "Test2",
      "plu": "9002",
      "articleGroupId": "c2ac3dfc-c176-4655-b725-ae6eb01c60a7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the `article->id` matches with some `lineItem->referenceId`.

I'm creating a ksql stream from the Kafka topic containing this data using:

```
CREATE STREAM receipts WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='receipts', VALUE_FORMAT='avro');
```

What I want to do is answer the following question: *within a given time frame* (say 1 hour)*, how many of each article were sold, and how much revenue did they result in?*

Essentially, from what I can see, I need a deduplicated list of `articles` which is then joined on the `lineItems`.

In plain SQL, this might look as follows (provided these entries were records in a relational database) for a global sales overview:

```sql
WITH articles_deduplicated AS (
    SELECT id, name, plu, articleGroupId
    FROM articles
    GROUP BY id, name, plu, articleGroupId
)
SELECT name, plu, articleGroupId, SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity, SUM(line_total) AS sum_total 
FROM articles_deduplicated INNER JOIN line_items
ON article.id = line_item.referenceId
GROUP BY name, plu, articleGroupId
```

My question is: **how can I translate this into ksql**?

I thought that I would be able to do the following to be able to answer this in `ksqlDB`:

1. Produce a stream of exploded `articles`

```
CREATE STREAM articles_exploded AS 
SELECT
  id,
  EXPLODE(articles) as article
FROM receipts
PARTITION BY id
```

This looks as follows:

```
ksql> select * from articles_exploded;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                                                         |ARTICLE                                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4                                       |{ID=3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c91d4a48bd26, NAME=Test1, PLU=9001, ARTICLEGROU|
|                                                                           |PID=c2ac3dfc-c176-4655-b725-ae6eb01c60a7}                                  |
|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4                                       |{ID=aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-da18a7de082a, NAME=Test2, PLU=9002, ARTICLEGROU|
|                                                                           |PID=c2ac3dfc-c176-4655-b725-ae6eb01c60a7}                                  |
```

2. Produce a stream containing the individual fields of `article`, rekeyed on the `id`:

```
CREATE STREAM articles_single AS 
SELECT
  article->id as article_id,
  article->name,
  article->plu,
  article->articlegroupid as article_group_id,
  id AS source_id
FROM articles_exploded
PARTITION BY article->id
```

This looks as follows:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|ARTICLE_ID                          |NAME                                |PLU                                 |ARTICLE_GROUP_ID                    |SOURCE_ID                           |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c91d4a48bd26|Test1                               |9001                                |c2ac3dfc-c176-4655-b725-ae6eb01c60a7|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4|
|aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-da18a7de082a|Test2                               |9002                                |c2ac3dfc-c176-4655-b725-ae6eb01c60a7|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4|
```

3. Afterwards, I create a *table* containing the deduplicated articles:

```
CREATE TABLE articles AS
SELECT 
  article_id, 
  EARLIEST_BY_OFFSET(source_id) AS source_id,
  EARLIEST_BY_OFFSET(name) as name,
  EARLIEST_BY_OFFSET(plu) as plu,
  COUNT(*) AS num_bookings
FROM articles_single 
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY article_id;
```

This looks as follows:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|ARTICLE_ID               |WINDOWSTART              |WINDOWEND                |SOURCE_ID                |NAME                     |PLU                      |NUM_BOOKINGS             |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-d|1699545600000            |1699549200000            |5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-3|Test2                    |9002                     |1                        |
|a18a7de082a              |                         |                         |6e926e9aac4              |                         |                         |                         |
|3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c|1699545600000            |1699549200000            |5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-3|Test1                    |9001                     |1                        |
|91d4a48bd26              |                         |                         |6e926e9aac4              |                         |                         |                         |
```

4. Produce a stream containing the exploded `lineItems`:

```
 CREATE STREAM line_items_exploded AS
 SELECT
  id,
  EXPLODE(lineitems) AS line_item
FROM receipts
PARTITION BY id
```

This looks as follows:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                                                                            |LINE_ITEM                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4                                                          |{BASEPRICE=5.0, LINETOTAL=5.0, PRICEMODIFIERS=[], QUANTITY=1, REFERENCEID=3a37825f-6739-4f39-9|
|                                                                                              |b90-c91d4a48bd26, PARENTITEMID=null, TAXRATE=7.0, TYPE=ARTICLE, UNITPRICE=5.0}                |
|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4                                                          |{BASEPRICE=3.0, LINETOTAL=3.0, PRICEMODIFIERS=[], QUANTITY=1, REFERENCEID=aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-8|
|                                                                                              |1e6-da18a7de082a, PARENTITEMID=null, TAXRATE=7.0, TYPE=ARTICLE, UNITPRICE=3.0}                |
```

5. Produce another stream containing the individual fields of `line_item`, rekeyed on `referenceId`:

```
CREATE STREAM line_items_single AS
 SELECT
  line_item->referenceId AS reference_id,
  id AS source_id,
  line_item->basePrice AS base_price,
  line_item->quantity,
  line_item->lineTotal AS line_total
FROM line_items_exploded
PARTITION BY line_item->referenceId
```

Finally, this looks as follows:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|REFERENCE_ID                        |SOURCE_ID                           |BASE_PRICE                          |QUANTITY                            |LINE_TOTAL                          |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c91d4a48bd26|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4|5.000                               |1                                   |5.000                               |
|aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-da18a7de082a|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4|3.000                               |1                                   |3.000                               |
```

Afterwards, I thought I could perform the following query:

```
ksql> select * from line_items_single join articles on line_items_single.reference_id = articles.id;
```

But this yields the following:

```
Can not join windowed source to non-windowed source.
`LINE_ITEMS_SINGLE` is not windowed
`ARTICLES` is TUMBLING windowed
```

This is [documented](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/join-streams-and-tables/#stream-table-joins) in the relevant dev guide section:

> Stream-table joins are always non-windowed joins. You can perform table lookups against a table when a new record arrives on the stream. Only events arriving on the stream side trigger downstream updates and produce join output. Updates on the table side don't produce updated join output.

My question is: **how would I solve this problem otherwise**? I thought about potentially using a `Stream-Stream` join and enriching either `articles` or `line_items_single` with information in the other, but the requirement for the `article` data to be deduplicated logically requires, from what I can see, a `Stream-Table` join.

If I remove the `WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 HOUR)` from my `articles` Table query, I can do the following:

```
select 
    articles.source_id, 
    articles.article_id, 
    name, 
    plu, 
    latest_by_offset(num_bookings) as total_bookings,
    latest_by_offset(base_price) as base_price, 
    sum(quantity) as sum_quantity, 
    sum(line_total) as sum_total 
from line_items_single 
join articles 
    on line_items_single.reference_id = articles.article_id 
group by articles.source_id, article_id, name, plu emit changes;
```

I *do* get the result that I want (note that I produced some more records in the meantime, hence why the numbers are higher):

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
|SOURCE_ID                           |ID                                  |NAME                  |PLU                   |TOTAL_BOOKINGS        |BASE_PRICE            |SUM_QUANTITY          |SUM_TOTAL             |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4|aa3892ad-e5ca-4b26-81e6-da18a7de082a|Test2                 |9002                  |7                     |3.000                 |5                     |15.000                |
|5952eb83-e227-4a6b-8d78-36e926e9aac4|3a37825f-6739-4f39-9b90-c91d4a48bd26|Test1                 |9001                  |7                     |5.000                 |5                     |25.000                |
```

But from a logical standpoint it doesn't make sense for me for `articles` to *not* be windowed since we would otherwise be building a global table over the entire stream. Since the number of entries may be quite large, this seems counter-intuitive.

Is there a more elegant solution that I'm not seeing, or have I misunderstood the windowing concepts?

Comment: FWIW, I've crossposted to the [Confluent forums](https://forum.confluent.io/t/facing-issues-with-complex-data-processing-use-case/9046) in hopes of getting a bit more exposure on this. It is a complex processing use-case, but I simply refuse to believe that it has not come up before...